# how to include xfeatures2d, SIFT in opencv 2.4.9.1

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to execute opencv tutorial related to Homography but It shows some errors while running on python 2.7 and opencv version 2.4.9.1. The code goes here:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
    img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)          # queryImage
    img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0) # trainImage
    # Initiate SIFT detector
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
    kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
    index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
    search_params = dict(checks = 50)
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []
    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
            good.append(m)
    if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good 
    ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good 
    ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
        matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
        h,w,d = img1.shape
        pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] 
    ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
        img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, 
        cv2.LINE_AA)
    else:
        print( "Not enough matches are found - 
        {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
        matchesMask = None
        draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in 
        green color
               singlePointColor = None,
               matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
               flags = 2)
    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)
    plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

For the above code I get the following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/anv-pc/Desktop/Homography_TemplateMatching.py", line 
    8, in <module>
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'\
```

How to solve this? Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `xfeatures2d` is for OpenCV 3.0 and newer. For OpenCV 2.4.9 you need to look for `nonfree`. Also your code assumes OpenCV >= 3.0. Search for a tutorial for the correct OpenCV version, or just use version 3.2 instead of an obsolete one

Comment: @Miki After your suggestion, Now I have installed opencv 3.0.0 but the error still persists. I have also checked the version of opencv after installation and it shows 3.0.0. Any other solution?

Comment: Have you recompiled OpenCV with contrib modules?

Comment: Yes. Installed opencv using this link. https://gist.github.com/minhoolee/b05d6c2164935a29fbf67790fac61e40

Comment: That link doesn't seem to install contrib modules

Comment: Sir, will you please post some link or steps how to install the contrib modules.

Comment: Tried installing opencv contrib modules using the below link, but still facing problems. https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Comment: Solved. Removed opencv completely and followed the opencv installation link - http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html